# set value of pandas ffill

Tags: python, pandas

I want exactly the same behaviour as pandas dataframe.fillna('ffill') method but instead of using the last non-NaN value, I want to pick the value myself, for example

`[NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN]`

should become

```
[NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

with the method call df.fillnan(0, 'ffill').

I can achieve this by iterating through each value in each row of the dataframe but want to know if there is a more optimal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for filtering non missing values after forward filling:

```
s = pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, 2, np.NaN, 4, 5, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN])
print (s)
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     NaN
6     4.0
7     5.0
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
dtype: float64

s = s.where(s.ffill().isnull(), s.fillna(0))
print (s)
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     0.0
6     4.0
7     5.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Solutiond for working by rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,5,np.nan],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,np.nan,np.nan],
         'D':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan],
         'E':[np.nan] * 6,

})

df1 = df.where(df.ffill(axis=1).isnull(), df.fillna(0)) 
print (df1)
     B    C    D    E
0  NaN  7.0  0.0  0.0
1  NaN  8.0  0.0  0.0
2  4.0  9.0  0.0  0.0
3  NaN  4.0  0.0  0.0
4  5.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Another solution with boolean mask created by check non missing values, [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df1 = df.where(df.notnull().cumsum(axis=1).eq(0), df.fillna(0))
print (df1)
     B    C    D    E
0  NaN  7.0  0.0  0.0
1  NaN  8.0  0.0  0.0
2  4.0  9.0  0.0  0.0
3  NaN  4.0  0.0  0.0
4  5.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Perfect.  And to make the same work row wise in a dataframe (which was my exact use case, although I didn't make clear in my question) you can just pass axis=1 in the ffill() method.

Comment: @Aesir - Not in [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) ?

Comment: df.where(df.ffill(axis=1).isnull(), df.fillna(0)) will work, leaving NaNs to the left of the first non-NaN in a row as NaN and setting NaNs to the right of first non-NaN as zero.

Comment: @Aesir - Now understand, it is like `df.where(df.fillna(axis=1, method='ffill').isnull(), df.fillna(0)) `

Comment: exactly! Thanks